# Where was the space station this morning?

Tags: low-earth-orbit

Did the space station fly over North Carolina this morning (January 22, 2019) about 6:30am   I live in Roxbro NC 27574.   I spotted an unusual object in the sky about 140-150 degrees, toward the South East.  It seemed to have 5 bright lights with a larger one in the middle.  There seemed to be another object behind it.  I used binoculars to see it up close.

Comment: Check [in-the-sky](https://in-the-sky.org/satpasses.php?day=24&month=7&year=2018&mag=3&anysat=v0&group=1&s=) — they have a nice page to show you bright satellite passes from your location at a given time. Almost all satellites and the ISS will appear as point lights, not a cluster of lights, so it’s more likely that you saw aircraft.

Comment: @RussellBorogove OP used binoculars. Usually [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) is better for lights in the sky, but I think the ISS could have some visible structure in binoculars.

Answer (score 3):

According to [In-The-Sky](https://in-the-sky.org/satpasses.php?day=21&month=1&year=2019&mag=3&anysat=v0&group=1&s=), there was no ISS pass visible from your location at that time, but the Hubble Space Telescope passed from WSW through S to SE from 6:34 to 6:41 am -- its highest elevation was 23º above horizon from Durham, so I believe it would be a little lower from Roxboro. I wouldn't expect it to appear as multiple light sources even in binoculars, however.

Similar HST passes are going to occur the morning of the 23rd at 6:24-6:30 and on the 24th at 6:14-6:19, so if you make similar observations at those times it's good confirmation that you're looking at HST.

ISS will be very bright the evening of the 23rd 6:47-6:52 pm going from WSW to NNE.

There are phone apps to help you find these satellites; I like Sky Guide on iOS.